# Calculating primes; Program works/Crashes past 6657;

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, primes

I'm trying to teach myself some CPP by writing a program that calculates prime numbers up to the a specific number.  I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 on a laptop with 3rd Gen i5@2.8GHz(x4)with 8GB of RAM on Win 8.1 Pro(x64).  I'm new to cpp(probably obvious) but I'm hoping to get this program working past 6657 and much higher. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

EDIT: This the new version of the program working as intended and using vectors. Thanks for your help!

```
/*
* Prime finder, starts at 2 works up, was working initially
* to 6658, now can run to 150000(highest tested yet) in ~17m25s.
* May need optimization. Uses vector size to check for nth number.
* Must have #include <vector>
*/

std::vector<int> prime;  // required for program to work. 
int primes(unsigned y){
    using namespace std;
    unsigned b = 0;
    bool z = true; prime.push_back(2);
    for (b = 2; prime.size() <= y; b++){
        if (b % 2 == 0 && b < y){ b++; }//catches even numbers.
        //finds primes to the nth integer
                /*decrementing in this loop produced a strange
                 *end count, used increments instead counts fixed
                 *and program completes sooner.
                 */

            for (unsigned j = 2; j < prime.size(); j++){
                //if (j > y){ return 0; }//catches infinite loop                
                if (prime.at(j) >= (b/2))
                    //removes unneccessary checking
                {break;}
                if (b%prime.at(j) == 0)
                {z = false; j = prime.size();}
            }
            if (z == true){ prime.push_back(b); }
            z = true;
        }
    }return 0;
}
```

Comment: array index out of bounds: Use an already implemented data structure like vector instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

int prime[] = {0};// required for program to work. Must be initialized.

creates space for exactly ONE prime number.

So when you do `prime[1]`, `prime[j-1]` for values of `j > 1` or `prime[a]` where `a > 1`, you are going out of bounds for the array.

You will need to either:

1. Use `vector<int> prime` and `prime.push_back(i);`
2. Use `int prime[SOMENUMBER] = { 0 };`

Using `vector<int>` also has the benefit that you don't need to store `prime[0]` with the number of primes. Instead you have a `prime.size()` function that tells you how many elements there are.

Comment: I had looked into vector before, but I was having trouble using them the way the sites explained it and showed the syntax.  I've since used method 2 to get the program working and indeed it does. Thank you for the help.  That being said I'll probably rewrite it once I learn how to use vectors. I didn't know that array sizes needed to be constant.  Vectors sounds like the way I need to go if I'm after the nth number. Definitely informative.

Answer (score 3):

```
int prime[] = {0};
```

That array is only of the size one, but you adress larger indexes later. This should not work for any other value than zero, but you are lucky for some reason. Try increasing the array size or work with a dynamic one.